# Retrofit2 SocketTimeOutException

Tags: android, retrofit2, socket-timeout-exception

I setup for `Retrofit`:

```
private Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (!NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE)
                        .build();
            }
            Response response = chain.proceed(request); //Exception here

            if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                String cacheControl = request.cacheControl().toString();
                response = response.newBuilder()
                        .removeHeader("Pragma")
                        .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                        .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl)
                        .build();
            } else {
                int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
                response = response.newBuilder()
                        .removeHeader("Pragma")
                        .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                        .build();
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
```

And I use to setup cache:

```
builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cookieJar(new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(Apploader.context)))
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .cache(cache)
                    .connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Sometime when server response too long My Application crash because `SocketTimeOut`

It break on line:  `Response response = chain.proceed(request);`  as I comment.
`SocketTimeOut` is subclass of `IOException`, why my code can't catch it.
How do I resolved this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use `OkHttpClient` for more configurations, like follwing :

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

and then set this `okHttpClient` with `RetrofitBuilder`,

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(okHttpClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use retrofit Callback method to easily handle exception that occurs during retrofit call. It has onResponse() and onFailure() override methods. 
If the retrofit call is succeeded then onResponse() will trigger, If the call is failure or any exception is occur then onFailure() will trigger.

You can refer below tutorials for a better idea about retrofit call backs

https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: Hi @EKN, Please see my update. I use Interceptor to configure for Cache. How do I catch onFaild here.

Comment: If you're using a custom OkHttp Interceptor, you could handle the `SocketTimeOutException` inside the overridden `intercept()` function, or by wrapping the web service client call. See the guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697459/handle-exceptions-thrown-by-a-custom-okhttp-interceptor-in-kotlin-coroutines#65469952